# SQL QUERY of count

Tags: database

find the department (ID) wise counts in the company.

```
Schema "employee" contains "employee_id", "employee_name", "dept_id"
```

i have write this is this correct or wrong?

```
select count(dept_id) as dept_vise_count

from employee e depart d

where e.dept_id = d.dept_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT    COUNT(d.dept_id) as dept_vise_count
FROM      employee e 
LEFT JOIN depart d ON (d.dept_id = e.dept_id)
GROUP BY  d.dept_id
```

Comment: left join is used for joining the table of department? can you provide me brief detail of this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear your answer:

Try something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(d.dept_id) as dept_vise_count
FROM employee e 
JOIN depart d
ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id;
GROUP BY d.dept_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use join.

```
 select count(dept_id) as dept_vise_count
 from employee e JOIN depart d
 ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id;
```